# Android Facebook API: POST event with picture

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, post

In my app I allow users to post Facebook events . I also want to attach a picture of the event
in the POST request i made, but i don't know how to do it. 
I read the documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#events) but sadly a picture parameter is not listed.  Do you know how to do that?

My post request works and looks like this:

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("name", event.getName());
    bundle.putString("start_time", event.getStartStringDate());
    bundle.putString("end_time", event.getEndStringDate());
    bundle.putString("location_id", event.getPlaceId());
    Request postRequest = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "me/events", bundle,
            HttpMethod.POST, new Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    Log.e("", response.toString()); 
                    pm.setPlace(null);

                }
            });
    postRequest.executeAsync();
}
```

I tried convert the picture into byte[] and add picture parameter in two ways without success (the request fail) :

```
        bundle.putByteArray("source", imgByteArray);
```

and

```
        bundle.putByteArray("picture", imgByteArray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not in the parameter list, then it's not possible to do it in one request.

Consider creating the event first, get the event ID, and then using the /EVENT_ID/picture endpoint to create the photo. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/#picture

Comment: thanks, this is the right way to do it! How can I convert my bitmap to put it in the "source" field (multipart/form-data) in my Request?

Comment: You should be able to use this method https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Request#Request(Session, String, Bundle, HttpMethod, Callback) and pass in the Bundle with bundle.putParcelable("source", bitmap)

Comment: I tried but I get this error response from FB servers: "HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 324, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#324) Missing or invalid image file}, isFromCache:false"

Comment: How are you getting the image and putting it in the bundle? Can you post some code?

Comment: sure, I'm getting the image in this way: `                        Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                                R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos);
                        Bundle bndPostImage = new Bundle();
                        bndPostImage.putParcelable("source", bi);`

Comment: Yeah, instead of writing the byte array, try to convert it back to a bitmap after you compress, and put the compressed bitmap object directly in the Bundle instead. I think the parcelling may be different.

Comment: I tried to put the bitmap inside the bundle without compressing it, but unfortunately I get the same error message "#324: Missing or invalid image file"